# For a certain product, cost C and revenue R are given as follows, where x is the number of units sold in hundreds:

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Cost: $C^2=x^2+96 \sqrt x+60$

Revenue: $892(x-5)^2+22R^2=18502$.

Find the marginal cost $dC\over dx$ at $x=5$

Answer (score 0):

Well, the function C does not depend on R so you can just ignore Revenue for now.

Cost is given as $C^2$ so you have to use implicit differentiation to find its derivative.

$$2C {dC \over dx} = {2x} + {96\over {2 \sqrt x}}$$

Then solve for ${dC \over dx}$ and plug in x = 5.